# OpenCV with multithreading in C++

Tags: c++, opencv, openmp, tbb

i'm trying to use a blurring filter with OpenCV, but I was told that there's a OpenCV multithread library, instead of using OpenMP or TBB. I've been trying to find the way to use it but I cannot.

In case I have to use OpenMP or TBB, which one works better for my filter? I'm familiar with OpenMP, but if TBB works better I have no problem learning it.

Comment: Did you try to use cv::setNumThreads? If this does not work, consider rebuilding latest version of OpenCV. The git version support at least Pthread, OpenMP and TBB (see CMake options). Also, note that rewriting a blurring filter seems to be rather a bad idea as OpenCV do it quite efficiently and it may be difficult to do this better.

Comment: It doesn't work, so I suppose I have to use the latest OpenCV. Thanks!